# Processing of Port Wine Failed

Tags: terminal, xcode, macports

I was in the process of installing Wine on terminal (via Macports), and encountered this hurdle while "computing dependencies":

"--->  Verifying checksums for xorg-libpthread-stubs

Error: org.macports.checksum for port xorg-libpthread-stubs returned: libpthread-stubs-0.3.tar.bz2 does not exist in /opt/local/var/macports/distfiles/xorg-libpthread-stubs

Error: Failed to install xorg-libpthread-stubs
Please see the log file for port xorg-libpthread-stubs for details:

/opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_x11_xorg-libpthread-stubs/xorg-libpthread-stubs/main.log"

Not sure how to proceed from here. Am far from adept at this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

For Wine under OS X I use [Wine_1.7.36.dmg](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/wine/builds/Wine_1.7.36.dmg) from "Wine.app Downloads" on [kronenberg.org](http://winebottler.kronenberg.org/downloads) and [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) and both install and work nicely without the need to use MacPorts.

Comment: Thank you. If I may ask I follow-up question: Would I have to download XQuartz stable or development? Does the PC software (in this case a game) still have to be installed via Terminal?

Comment: As a general rule, I always download the stable versions of whatever I'm downloading.  As to installing WinApps, I usually just run the `setup.exe` (double-click it in Finder) and it loads both `XQuartz` and `Wine` automatically to then proceed with the install as if it were being done under Windows.